# Stored words and predictive text not working

Tags: keyboard, text-prediction

I have a Galaxay Tab A SM-T580 running Android 7.0. I cannot get the predictive text to work on the Samsung keyboard; all the options are enabled but it only shows the letters I am typing. I have done a factory reset and it is still not working.